# Style.visibility = “hidden” on a table leaves the vertical scroll bar exposed

Tags: javascript

I have a div wrapper `(class=“wrap”)` on my quite small table `(id=“myTable”)`. When I use

```
document.getElementById(“myTable”).style.visibility = “hidden”
```

the table disappears but the vertical scroll bar remains (no horizontal scroll). The same process works well on other tables but this table uses the wrapper and borrowed code to provide static header and footer with scrollable rows and I only vaguely understand how it works so messing around with it is fraught for me. I can pour on the code but first I'm wondering if the symptom is indicative of a particular error on my part.

Comment: can you add your code snippet or a demo of the issue you are facing?

Comment: `visibilility: hidden;` doesn't hide the element from DOM. It keeps the element in DOM but you can't see the element as the element is transparent. Use `overflow: hidden;` to hide scrollbars.

Comment: OK, I've tried various ways to set this dynamically, but none work. ie document.getElementById(“myTable”).style.overflow = “hidden”;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! I needed to address the wrapper and use overflowY instead of overflow-y.

document.getElementById("wrapper").style.overflowY = "hidden";

and make it appear by using:

document.getElementById("table-scroll").style.overflowY = "auto";

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the overflow property :-

`overflow-y: hidden;`

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can I do that dynamically.